# Reluctant Qualifiers in Pattern Matching

Tags: java, regex

I have following programm

```
public class PatternMatching {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String pattern ="a??";
                Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                String findAgainst = "a";
                Matcher matcher = pattern1.matcher(findAgainst);
                int count=0;
                while(matcher.find()){
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)+".start="+ matcher.start()+".end="+matcher.end());
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
```

which prints following output

```
.start=0.end=0
.start=1.end=1
2
```

instead of

```
.start=0.end=0
a.start=0.end=1
.start=1.end=1
3
```

when I run the program with pattern `"b??"`
the output is

```
.start=0.end=0
.start=1.end=1
2
```

which is correct. What would be the reason for incorrect output eventhough it is a reluctant qualifier?

Comment: You actually have 3 matches when testing `a??` against `a`.

Comment: right, but the above program doesn't output that. Which is strange

Comment: The same behavior is in JS with manual advancing the index. Looks like it is the internal regex library issue when dealing with zero-length matches.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the issue is that Java regex engine uses the following algorithm when encountering a zero-length match: it compares the index of the match to the current regex index, and if they coincide, the regex index is incremented.

Thus, when you matched the empty space before `a` with `a??` the regex engine found a zero-length match and incremented the index that appeared *after* `a`, thus, skipping a correct match.

If you use a greedy version - `a?` - the output will be different:

```
a.start=0.end=1
.start=1.end=1
2
```

It happens because the first `a` was consumed, the regex engine index is after `a`, and can now match the end-of-string.